# sudo in expect script

Tags: expect, sudo

How to use sudo with an expect script ? Like I want to do

```
spawn sudo apt-get install wine
expect "*?assword: "
send "$passwd\r"
interact
```

But it does not send password. How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set user as sudoer, it can skip password validation.

Comment: I want to do password validation

Comment: Then you can use -S option. sudo -S apt-get install wine

Comment: echo $password | sudo -S apt-get ... I thought this will help you, why don't you want -S.